# UITableviewController messes with contentInset of editable UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiwebview

I've got a UITableViewController with several sections, dynamically created. One of the rows in each section contains a UIWebView as its accessoryView. The UIWebView is prepopulated with HTML to allow the text within it to be edited. When the UIWebView is tapped, the tableView scrolls so that the row containing the UIWebView is above the keyboard; the keyboard appears and the UIWebView becomes the first responder. This works fine if the UIWebView is at the top of the tableView so the table does not need to be scrolled. If however a lower down row is tapped so that the table has to be scrolled, then the contentInset of the UIWebView's scrollView gets changed. Specifically, the bottom value of the contentInset is added to, making the UIWebView long and thin instead of rectangular.

I have uploaded screenshots to show this:

Before selecting UIWebView:
[image: Before selecting UIWebView]

After selecting UIWebView:
[image: After selecting UIWebView]

After the UIWebView resigns first responder status and the keyboard is dismissed, it returns to normal.

I know it is the contentInset property which is being adjusted because I have added an observer of the webView's scrollView using the keyValue "contentInset" and I can observe it changing, and even then log it and confirm that it has changed.

Comment: I have reproduced the problem in a test app. It behaves exactly the same way on a real iPad 3 running iOS 8, and the iPad 2 simulator under iOS 7 and iOS 8. Here's a link to the test app: [link](http://www.mashley.net/Test.zip)   Tap on the top UIWebView and all is well. Tap on one of the lower ones when they are below where the keyboard would be and the contentInset of the webView gets messed up. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: It turns out that the same issue occurs if the UIWebViews are added as subViews of a plain UIScrollView. I have uploaded an updated test app here: [link](http://www.mashley.net/Test2.zip) If you select one of the lower webViews to bring up the keyboard and then scroll up so that the webView is visible then you will see that the contentInset of the webView has been adjusted.

Comment: Further information: implementing TPKeyboardAvoiding ([link](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)) solves this problem but I have no idea why. I'm in the process of stripping TPKeyboardAvoiding down to bare bones to provide just what I need for my code in order to try and identify what specifically it is doing differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem wasn't the contentInset, it was the contentOffset of the UIWebView's built in UIScrollView. Here's how I fixed it:

```
@interface SomeViewController ()
@property BOOL monitorContentOffsetChanges;
@end

@implementation SomeViewController

- (void)webViewCreationMethod {
    UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    //Setup webView

    //Observe any changes to the scrollView's contentOffset property
    [[webView scrollView] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:0 context:NULL];
    [self setMonitorContentOffsetChanges:YES];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
//The webView's contentOffset was changed
  if (object == [[self webView] scrollView] && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"] && [self monitorContentOffsetChanges]) {
         //Stop responding to changes in the contentOffset to prevent recursive calling of this method
        [self setMonitorContentOffsetChanges:NO];
        //Force the contentOffset back to zero
        [[[self webView] scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
        //Start monitoring changes to the contentOffset again in case of future changes
        [self setMonitorContentOffsetChanges:YES];
    }
}

@end
```

This solution is required because UIWebView's scrollView property is read only, so you can't subclass UIScrollView and override setContentOffset to take no action and force this into the UIWebView.

The only thing I'm not sure of now is whether this solution is App Store safe.

Comment: Oh I forgot, you have to include [self setMonitorContentOffsetChanges:YES] otherwise the observer will never take action.